# Python's subprocess module returning different results from Unix shell

Tags: python, unix

I'm trying to get a list of the CSV files in a directory with python. This is really easy within unix:

```
ls -l *.csv
```

And, predictably, I get a list of the files that end with .csv in my directory. However, when I attempt the Python equivalent using the Subprocess module:

```
>>> import subprocess as sp
>>> sp.Popen(["ls", "-l", "*.csv"], stdout = sp.PIPE)
<subprocess.Popen object at 0xb780e90c>
>>> ls: cannot access *.csv: No such file or directory
```

Can somebody please explain what's going on?

**Edit**: Adding `shell = True` removes the error, but instead of getting a list of just CSV files, I get a list of *all* the files in the directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it to behave as it does at the shell, you need to pass `shell=True` (your mileage may vary here, depending on your system and shell).  In your case the problem is that when you do `ls -l *.csv`, the *shell* is evaluating what * means, not `ls`. (`ls` is merely formatting your results, but the shell has done the heavy lifting to determine what files match `*.csv`).  Subprocess makes `ls` treat `*.csv` literally, and look for a file with that specific name, which of course there aren't any (since that's a pretty hard filename to create).

What you really should be doing is using `os.listdir` and filtering the names yourself.

Comment: I've followed yours and Weeble's suggestions, but now I get a list of all the files in the directory, not just the CSV files I want. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: OK, I've figured out how to solve my problem using Python's `glob` module - much simpler overall. However, I still want to know what's going on.

Comment: Ah-hah!  :-)  I almost suggested using the `glob` module, but I didn't think it was quite what you wanted (but it addresses the same problem).  In general you shouldn't trust `subprocess` to accurately replicate shell behaviour - it may on some systems, but not on others.

Comment: Thanks. I guess this goes as another example against using the shell and ignoring python's library. :D

Comment: @Nick, what does `/bin/sh -c ls -l *.csv` do for you when you type it at a shell prompt?  for me (on Linux) it works just like `ls` (ignoring the rest of the args) -- and that `/bin/sh` command is what shell=True with a list (instead of a string) is specified as doing.

Comment: @Tom, if and when you want to use the shell (maybe not for `ls`, but many other tasks are harder to replicate in Python) of course you can: just use a string (and shell=True) in `Popen`, not a list (the list is fine when you **don't** need shell functionality and thus use `shell=False`, explicitly or by default).

Comment: @Alex: using sh gives me the results you get...using ksh gets me good results, probably because of how the argument parser works.

Comment: @Alex: actually I lie...I'd aliased ksh -c to quote the arguments, which is the only reason why that worked and /bin/sh didn't.  I suppose the only way to get this to work with `shell=True` is to quote the command in its' entirety.

Comment: @Nick, yes, "pass a string" (instead of a list) when you're using shell=True, as I suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html?highlight=glob#module-glob) instead?  It's going to be faster than "shelling out"!

```
import glob
glob.glob('*.csv')
```

This gives you just the names, not all the extra info `ls -l` supplies, though you can get extra info with `os.stat` calls on files of interest.

If you really must use `ls -l`, I think you want to pass it as a string for the shell to do the needed star-expansion:

```
proc = sp.Popen('ls -l *.csv', shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE)
```

Comment: Yes, I discovered glob seconds before I saw your post. :P. However, I still want to figure out why Python can't produce the same output as the shell.

Comment: @Tom, sure it can -- "/bin/sh -c ls -l '*.csv'" (which as the docs say is the exact equivalent of shell=True with a list instead of a string) behaves just the same way, listing all file names -- try it!  When you want the behavior you'd get by typing at the shell a plain string, you give `Popen` the same string (with shell=True), as I said.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter `ls -l *.csv` at the shell, the shell itself expands `*.csv` into a list of all the filenames it matches. So the arguments to ls will actually be something more like `ls -l spam.txt eggs.txt ham.py`

The ls command doesn't understand wildcards itself. So when you pass the argument `*.csv` to it it tries to treat it as a filename, and there is no file with that name. As Nick says, you can use the `shell=True` parameter to have Python invoke a shell to run the subprocess, and the shell will expand the wildcards for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
p=subprocess.Popen(["ls", "-l", "*.out"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

causes

```
/bin/sh -c ls -l *.out
```

to be executed.

If you try this command in a directory, you'll see -- in typical mystifying-shell fashion --  all files are listed. And the `-l` flag is ignored as well. That's a clue.

You see, the `-c` flag is picking up only the `ls`. The rest of the arguments are being eaten up by `/bin/sh`, not by `ls`.

To get this command to work right at the terminal, you have to type

```
/bin/sh -c "ls -l *.out"
```

Now /bin/sh sees the full command "ls -l *.out" as the argument to the `-c` flag.

So to get this to work out right using `subprocess.Popen`, you are best off just passing the command as a single string

```
p=subprocess.Popen("ls -l *.out", stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output,error=p.communicate()
print(output)
```